# restore deleted y-axis

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder

Is there a way to add the y-axis back to a bar chart if it has been deleted?  Right now, all I have found to do is create a new chart and set it up again like my other chart, just not deleting the y-axis.  :/  I'm using Report Builder 2.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out.  Select the chart then, in the Properties pane under Chart, hit the '...' button next to ChartAreas (Collection).  That brings up a ChartArea Collection Editor window.  Under Axes in the right column, hit the '...' button next to CategoryAxes.  That brings up a ChartAxis Collection Editor window.  Under Appearance, toggle Visible to True.

Comment: That is so convoluted!  Surprised anyone could find that. :)